# Extracting data from an android phone

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to create a program or app which extracts information from a phone, such as SMS & Contacts.

I've tried to find information on the net but i am unable to find any relevant help.

I am not looking to be spoonfed, just to be pointed in the right direction, where should i start looking? and would a
 program or app be more efficient ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from official android docs. You can access that data with [Content Providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).